# Undefined reference to class when the class is defined

Tags: c++, class, reference, nested, undefined

Recently, I've started learning C++. Knowing some python already, I decided to try and understand pointers, but I've run into an error while trying to compile the file. The error message is a bit confusing, and I've been stuck on it for some time. Answers on SO do offer some insight on the problem, but as I am still new to C++ I don't really understand how to fix it. I've read that it might be a problem with the default constructor declaration, but I'm not really sure what to fix.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Uinter
    /*
     * Regrouping class for intervals (_Inter class) 
     * offering 3 different methods:
     *  "reunion(int bi, int bs)" -> Unites the interval pointed by "_tete"
     *                               with the one defined by [bi, bs]
     *  "printUinter()"           -> Prints the interval pointed by "_tete"
     *  "contient(int nb)"        -> Returns True if "nb" is present inside
     *                               the intervals, else False. 
     */
    {
        class _Inter
        /*
         * Class representing a single interval.
         * _bi stands for the lower limit of the interval.
         * _bs stands for the upper limit of the interval.
         */
        {
            int _bi, _bs;
            _Inter* _next;
        public:
            _Inter(int, int, _Inter*);
            // Defining getters and setters for the interval.
            void set_bi(int value)
                {_bi = value;}
            void set_bs(int value)
                {_bs = value;}
            void set_next(_Inter* value)
                {_next = value;}
            int get_bi()
                {return _bi;}
            int get_bs()
                {return _bs;}
            _Inter* get_next()
                {return _next;}
        };
        _Inter* _tete;
    public:
        Uinter(): _tete(nullptr){}
        void reunion(int bi, int bs)
            {
            if(_tete == nullptr)
                {
                _Inter new_interval = _Inter(bi, bs, nullptr);
                _tete = &new_interval;
                }
            else
                {
                if(bi < _tete->get_bi())
                    {
                    if (bs < _tete->get_bi())
                        {
                        _Inter new_interval = _Inter(bi, bs, _tete);
                        _tete = &new_interval;
                        }

                    else if (bs > _tete->get_bs())
                        {
                        _Inter new_interval = _Inter(bi, bs, _tete->get_next());
                        _tete = &new_interval;
                        }

                    else if (bs > _tete->get_bi())
                        {
                        _Inter new_interval = _Inter(bi, _tete->get_bs(), _tete->get_next());
                        _tete = &new_interval;
                        }                   
                    }
                else if (bi > _tete->get_bi())
                    {
                    if (bi > _tete->get_bs())
                        {
                        _Inter temp = *_tete->get_next(); // delete later
                        while(&temp != nullptr && bi > temp.get_bs())
                            {
                            temp = *temp.get_next();
                            }
                        if (&temp == nullptr)
                            {
                            _Inter new_interval = _Inter(bi, bs, nullptr);
                            //temp.set_next(new_interval);
                            }
                        else if (bi < temp.get_bi())   // bi < temp.get_bs()
                            {
                            if (bs < temp.get_bi())
                                {
                                _Inter new_interval = _Inter(bi, bs, _tete);
                                _tete = &new_interval;
                                }

                            else if (bs > temp.get_bs())
                                {
                                _Inter new_interval = _Inter(bi, bs, _tete->get_next());
                                _tete = &new_interval;
                                }

                            else if (bs > temp.get_bi())
                                {
                                _Inter new_interval = _Inter(bi, _tete->get_bs(), _tete->get_next());
                                _tete = &new_interval;
                                }                   
                            }
                        else if (bi > temp.get_bi())  // bi < temp.get_bs()
                            {
                            if (bs > temp.get_bs())
                                {
                                _Inter new_interval = _Inter(temp.get_bi(), bs, nullptr);
                                temp = new_interval;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        void printUinter();
        bool contient(int nb);
        void order();
    };


int main() 
{
    Uinter interval;
    interval.reunion(12, 23);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the error message -

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
g++ -std=c++11    -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_2 build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o 
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o: In function `Uinter::reunion(int, int)':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:56: undefined reference to `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:56:(.text$_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii[_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii]+0x3f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:65: undefined reference to `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:65:(.text$_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii[_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii]+0xa4): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:71: undefined reference to `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:71:(.text$_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii[_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii]+0xf7): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:77: undefined reference to `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:77:(.text$_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii[_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii]+0x154): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:99: undefined reference to `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:99:(.text$_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii[_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii]+0x23d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o:/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:105: more undefined references to `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)' follow
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o: In function `Uinter::reunion(int, int)':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:105:(.text$_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii[_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii]+0x28d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:111:(.text$_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii[_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii]+0x2e8): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.cpp:119:(.text$_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii[_ZN6Uinter7reunionEii]+0x349): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Iocust/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I am sorry for providing such an unclear code. If it is of any relevance, I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2.

Comment: The error message is correct. `Uinter::_Inter::_Inter(int, int, Uinter::_Inter*)` is not the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a linker error. The problem lies here:

```
public:
    _Inter(int, int, _Inter*);
```

You are not defining the constructor, but only declare it, so the linker complains (it finds the declaration but not the definition). You need the definition as without it, you cannot construct the object `_Inter`. If you don't provide any declaration for the constructor, then the compiler generates a default one for you, but in this case you provided a declaration, so there is no more default constructor generated.

You need to provide a definition for the `Uinter::_Inter` constructor, either inline

```
public:
    _Inter(int, int, _Inter*){/* definition here */}
```

or outside the class

```
Uinter::_Inter(int, int, _Inter*){/* definition here */}
```

And probably you'd want to name your constructor parameters

```
_Inter(int param1, int param2, _Inter* param3)
```

as you'll need them.

Comment: Thank you for the swift comment! I am sorry, but as I stated I am still inexperienced in C++. I thought that the line that you mentioned was the constructor itself. Is what I am doing only "declaring" the constructor?

Edit - Thank you for the insightful answer! I think I got it :)

Comment: You just tell the compiler that a function with that signature will be defined somewhere else, so you can use it before the full definition. See for example http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html PS: whenever at the end of the compilation you see something like `error: ld returned 1 exit status`, you have a linker error (`ld` is the name of the linker on UNIX-like platforms). So the code compiled correctly, but (most of the time) a definition is missing for some function that you use.